# IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2010 RC freezing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Every time I try to write something, IntelliSense freezes Visual Studio and I have to wait like 2 minutes for it to show code completion list. The only way I can work with is turning it completly off. **`

> **I've already installed the last IntelliSense patch from Microsoft but the problem doesn't seem to have gotten any better.**

Anyone had the same issue or knows what might be the problem? I'm using C#. I have a freshly installed version of Visual Studio 2010 RC, with no ReSharper, on a clean formated computer.

Thanks

Comment: ummm.. mightn't it be that vs10rc is a dog and has, unfortunately, already booked a first class cabin on the failboat? just sayin... sadly. (the vista of VS)

Comment: Not programming related. Report bugs at the MS Connect site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using UIA 2.0 (the default on XP and maybe Vista, I think).  If possible, can you try [upgrading to UIA 3.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971513/)?

The problem is that UIA 2.0 doesn't support virtualization, so the (rather large) completion lists have automation peers created for each item, and the algorithm that does this doesn't scale very well.  UIA 3.0 supports virtualization, so only the list items that are visible have automation peers created.

Comment: Yes, I'm downloading it right now. But first I'll have to install SP2.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's this bug:

https://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/09/intellisense-crash-in-ui-automation.aspx

If so, there's a patch available on that page.

Comment: I said in the original post that I already downloaded the crash intellisense patch..

Comment: @devoured elysium: Sorry, I must have skimmed past that line.  I guess I can't help you then.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes,it's just that is the second time since I madethe thread that someone doesn't read what I said and gave me that link as an answer..

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like you're not alone in experiencing this bug, see here for instance:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532783/very-slow-intellisense