# Visual Studio 2010 is slow (typing/intellisense etc)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

From time to time I'm struggling with Visual Studio 2010 being very slow. One thing that popped into my head is that perhaps VS stores some files (cache, solution settings etc) is locations that on my machine are mapped to remote locations (like user settings). Do you know where I can check paths that VS uses to store its files? Or perhaps you can think of other issues that cause VS to slow down?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270955/intellisense-in-visual-studio-2010-rc-freezing?rq=1 ?

Comment: as with each MS product: Restart usually solves the problem ;) - also check if you have tools like ReSharper installed - in most cases those are to blame

Comment: lol :) I'm waiting with ReSharper to install. Basically it's pure VS installation + subversion plugin. I'll try that Windows Automation API 3.0 and see the outcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that worked for me... honestly, i have no clue why it works but it's just a checkbox.

```
Go to
Tools ==> Options ==> Environment ==> General ==> Visual Experience

Then UNTICK
Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance

And UNTICK
Use graphics hardware acceleration if available
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/350495/Visual-Studio-WAS-painfully-slow

Comment: Please add the relevant information from the link to the answer, if the link dies, then the answer will be useless.

Comment: This worked for me too. 
The relevant information is:
Go to Tools/Options/Environment/General/Visual Experience
and untick "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" and "Use graphics hardware acceleration if available".

The funny thing is: Visually I see absolutely no difference. They should call their checkboxes simply "Make Slow" and "Make even slower" because they have no other influence ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only possible thing you could do is restart Visual Studio and if that doesn't work, restart your computer. You should also double check that you have the recommended memory space installed and available on your machine, and that other processes are not hogging it.